# matplotlib annotate xycoords=('data','axes fraction') => TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'0.99.1.1'
```

the following code runs:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
ax=plt.axes([.1, .1, .8, .8])
ax.annotate('++++', xy=(.5,.2), xycoords='data')
ax.annotate('aaaa', xy=(.5,.4), xycoords='axes fraction')
#ax.annotate('bbbb', xy=(.5,.6), xycoords=('data', 'axes fraction'))
plt.show()
```

but the commented-out ax.annotate gives an error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

it is supposedly correct code according to the current docs:

```
From: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/annotations_guide.html

4. A tuple of two coordinate specification. 
   The first item is for x-coordinate and 
   the second is for y-coordinate. 
   For example,

        annotate("Test", xy=(0.5, 1), xycoords=("data", "axes fraction"))

    0.5 is in data coordinate, and 1 is in normalized axes coordinate.
```

any ideas on what is going on?

EDIT:
since first posting, i have been looking at a workaround, and discovered another issue. When xycoords='data', the annotataion is still clipped if it falls outside the axes, even with clip_on=False.  Here is the code that demonstrates this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
ax=plt.axes([.1, .1, .8, .8])
ax.annotate('cccc', xy=(.3, .5), xycoords='data', clip_on=False)
ax.annotate('dddd', xy=(.3,-.1), xycoords='data', clip_on=False)
ax.annotate('eeee', xy=(.6,-.1), xycoords='axes fraction', clip_on=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you using? Both of your examples work perfectly for me...

Comment: thanks Joe, matplotlib.__version__ '0.99.1.1' .... what version are you using?

Comment: @mike - `1.0.1` I think the "tuple of two coordinate specification" part of the `xcoords` kwarg was added in matplotlib 1.0.  See the addition on 2010-02-25 at http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/_static/CHANGELOG   The latter problem is probably a bug that was fixed at some point.  (In fact, I'd bet it was a bug that only existed in `0.99.1`. I don't think it'd go unnoticed for long.)

Comment: @mike - Actually, the latter problem persists even in newer versions of maplotlib. However, it's actually the expected behavior.  Have a look at the `annotation_clip` kwarg to annotate: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate

Comment: @Joe - ok, i now have 1.0.1 installed (without uninstalling or deleting 0.99.1.1) ... i'll report back on the results

Comment: @Joe - both xycoords=() and annotation_clip are working well !  thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a tuple to indicate different x and y transforms for `annotate` was added in matplotlib `1.0`.  [Here's the relevant commit](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/688a8892c61bfcc23b3d6cb4564e382fd6e3f6b0), if anyone's interested.  You'll need to upgrade to the latest version to use it.

For the second problem, this is actually the documented behavior.  (`clip_on` is a generic matplotlib text artist kwarg. Annotation artists don't behave in the same way, apparently.)

From: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate

> The annotation_clip attribute contols
>   the visibility of the annotation when
>   it goes outside the axes area. If
>   True, the annotation will only be
>   drawn when the xy is inside the axes.
>   If False, the annotation will always
>   be drawn regardless of its position.
>   The default is None, which behave as
>   True only if xycoords is”data”.

You'll need to use the `annotation_clip` kwarg, instead:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
ax=plt.axes([.1, .1, .8, .8])
ax.annotate('cccc', xy=(.3, .5), xycoords='data', annotation_clip=False)
ax.annotate('dddd', xy=(.3,-.1), xycoords='data', annotation_clip=False)
ax.annotate('eeee', xy=(.6,-.1), xycoords='axes fraction', annotation_clip=False)
plt.show()
```

See [this thread on the matplotlib-users list](http://old.nabble.com/plotting-an-arrow-outside-of-the-plot-does-not-work-any-more-td29552039.html) for more discussion (and also note that the `annotation_clip` kwarg might be broken on `0.99.1`, so you may need to use the workaround there.)